# Takes too long to loop through array looking for duplicates

Tags: c#, performance, loops

hope you can help me out.

I've got a 135.000 line long txt file containing lines like this: `111706469;1972WE;26;Wel`.

What the program is supposed to do, is compare every line to every line that came before it, to find if it's more than 80% similar and then state the line number of the original line.

Those things i've managed to do on my own like this.

```
            if (rows.Length > 1) {
                for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < rows.Length; rowIndex++) 
                {
                    string cols = rows[rowIndex];
                    bool Dubbel = false;

                    for (int DupIndex = 0; DupIndex < rowIndex; DupIndex++)
                    {
                        string SearchDup = rows[DupIndex];
                        decimal ComparisonResult = Compare(cols, SearchDup);

                        if (ComparisonResult > 80)
                        {
                            cols += ";" + DupIndex;
                            Dubbel = true;
                            break;
                        }  
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(rowIndex + ";" + cols); 
                }
            }
```

This means the program has to go through the array again and again for every array item. My question is, is there a faster/better way to doing this?

Any help you can give me would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just store all strings encountered before in dictionary, instead of looking up over and over. This would make your algorithm run in O(N) instead of O(N*N)

Comment: @Alexander - That should be an answer.  I'd upvote it.

Comment: The difficulty here is Compare method, which implies non-exact match. You cannot just store everything in dictionary and do exact matching. Perhaps implementation of Compare could shed some light. How do you find string similarity? Is it exact position matches, or there is some complicated parsing, perhaps hamming distance?

Comment: @Alexander - Oh, point.

Comment: Perhaps use [ternary search tree](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5819/Ternary-Search-Tree-Dictionary-in-C-Faster-String)?

Comment: @Alexander - Thank you for your suggestion, I'm certainly going to try it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your fuzzy matching, which returns a floating point number - there's no way to optimize this better than O(N*N) without any details on the fuzzy function itself *(if I'm wrong - please somebody correct me)*

If you have exact matches you can remove them first, this way your N^2 complexity will be reduced to (N-K)^2 - this operation will be worth it if you have at least some exact matches.

Use `HashSet<>`, which doesn't need a second object like `Dictionary`

```
List<string> rows = new List<string>(new[] {"AAA","BBB","AAA","CCC"});

HashSet<string> foundLines = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (string row in rows){
if (!foundLines.Contains(row))
    foundLines.Add(row);
}
rows = foundLines.ToList();
```

Then proceed with your algoritm

Comment: I do understand how would this give him if line is 80% of another line?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning ahh you're right - fuzzy comparison = no good

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to get much optimization without a significant overhaul.  It'd be trivial for exact matches, or for searching for anything which closely matched a target, but for a difference between objects, you *must* compare each item to each previous item.

Basically, if you're given a set of `N` strings, you have to compare `N` to `N-1`, `N-2`, `N-3`, etc.  Then you need to compare them all *again* with `N+1`, in addition to `N`, because there's no relationship between `N+1` and `N`.

Answer (score 0):

After some further efforts I've come to the anwser of my own question and thought I should post it incase someone else were to have the same problem.

I converted the txt file to a mysql database, then SELECTED'ed all the records once into a DataTable. The code then loops through the records and SELECT's from the original DataTable only those records with the same Postal code and house number into a second DataTable. Against which the original is compared.

This reduced a process that took 9 hours to 2 to 3 minutes. After the fact it was quite obvious, but such is hindsight...

Hope it helps someone out.